# xargs is not working with the replstr (replace-string)

Tags: linux, bash, xargs

Here's the command:

```
... | xargs -I arguu bash -c "bq load --replace --source_format=CSV -F\"\t\" --quote \"\" big-data-alpha:psql.arguu arguu.csv `cat arguu.header`"
```

But it tells me 'arguu.header No such file or direcory', seeming like that arguu is not replaced with what it should be.

Could anyone give me some idea?

Many thanks!

Comment: Could you give the final command here? I'm still confused upon ur description. thanks. @EtanReisner

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is when the `cat` command is being executed.

Inside double quotes backticks are evaluated. So when your shell sees your pipeline with `xargs` at the end it sees the double quoted string and scans it for variables, command substitution (backticks and the more modern `$()` format), etc. and performs them immediately.

So **before** anything about your pipeline happens (possibly not technically accurate as this might be broken down by pipeline segment but good enough for the current explanation) the `cat` command (with `arguu` in the command literally) is executed.

Hence the error.

The reason using `$''` quoting on the argument to `bash -c` is because inside single quotes (even the ANSI single quotes `$''`) variables, command substitution, etc. do **not** occur. So the backticks make it through to the `xargs`-run `bash` and it gets replaced and run appropriately.

Using normal single quotes (not the ANSI quotes) is the correct answer here (since you don't have anything in the string that you want expanded by the main shell).

This also means you don't need to escape the double quotes inside the string argument anymore.

This entire approach, however, is misguided and incorrect.

Starting with the fact that you are Parsing the output from `ls`.

That incorrect start leads directly to the need for `xargs` here and the problems that are related to it.

It seems that your goal here is to process every file that matches the `production*.csv` glob in the current directory through the command `bq load --replace --source_format=CSV --allow_quoted_newlines --skip_leading_rows 1 big-data-alpha:psql.$globbed $file $first_line_of_file` command.

This can be **much** more easily done by starting from a glob and a loop than it can by starting with parsing `ls`.

Namely:

```
for file in production*.csv; do
    stem=${file#production} # Strip "production" from the start of the filename.
    stem=${stem%.csv} # Strip ".csv" from the end of the filename.
    IFS= read firstline <"$file"
    echo "Processing $stem"
    bq load --replace --source_format=CSV --allow_quoted_newlines --skip_leading_rows 1 big-data-alpha:psql."$stem" "$file" "$firstline"
done
```

I've replaced the (relatively) costly sub-shell and external command invocation for `cat` and `head` in the original with an in-process use of `read` but that's not strictly necessary.

Comment: When I change it to `bash -c $'... $(cat ...)'`, it still complains **cat: production.arguu.csv: No such file or directory**

Comment: `production.arguu.csv` isn't in your question anywhere. Show the current attempted command?

Comment: Sry, it's **arguu.header**, I cv the wrong test scenario.

Comment: It seems like when executing small files, `bq` will not complain this error, but when the file is big, it always complains. Will it related with some posiible multi-thread things in `bq` internally that lead to this phenomenon?

Comment: `bq` isn't running the `cat` command in your code. Is it supposed to be? What is `bq`? Are you trying to pass it a series of commands to run somewhere/somehow else?

Comment: the result of cat command is the last parameter for `bq` command, which is provided by Google BigQuery, the internal implementation is not known

Comment: Right so then `bq` isn't running `cat` so errors *from* `cat` don't have anything to do with `bq` is my point. The problem is still that `cat` is executing before you intend it to. Show your current command and the **exact** current error?

Comment: `ll production*.csv | awk '{print $9}' | awk -F"." '{print $2}' | xargs -I arguu bash -c $'echo arguu; bq load --replace --source_format=CSV --allow_quoted_newlines --skip_leading_rows 1 big-data-alpha:psql.arguu production.arguu.csv $(cat production.arguu.csv | head -n 1)'` This is the exact command. As I said, the first two item will not complain errors. When it comes to the **challenge_submissions** item, it complains **cat: production.arguu.csv: No such file or directory**

Comment: If I execute `ll production*.csv | awk '{print $9}' | awk -F"." '{print $2}' | xargs -I arguu bash -c $'echo  $(cat production.arguu.csv | head -n 1)'`, everything works fine.

Comment: What do you mean "challenge_submissions`"? Also, really, stop using `$''` and just use `''`. Unless you need backslash escapes to be handled in the string you don't want `$"'` quoting. As written that command looks like it should be working fine but there are a number of things wrong with this approach to this problem. Starting with the [parsing of `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and the fact that replacing that with a loop would mean you don't need `xargs` at all.

Comment: Yep, I've tried replacing `$''` with `''`, it's the same. and the **challenge_submissions** is one of the outputs from `ll production*.csv | awk '{print $9}' | awk -F"." '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in command quote and parenthesis. Command are quoted, when invoking in shell(not shell your command run).

Change " characters into ' characters.

Comment: Could u be more specific, maybe give out the final command here. I don't quite get what u mean here. Thanks!

Comment: Is the problem solved? I doubt you should to put additional backslash before \t string.